# Check for metatype conformance dynamically

Tags: swift

In Swift, the "is" keyword can be used to check if a metatype conforms to another metataype.

```swift
protocol Edible {}
struct Broom {}
struct Bread: Edible {}

func isEdible(_ itemType: Any.Type) -> Bool {
    return itemType is Edible.Type
}

isEdible(Broom.self) // false
isEdible(Bread.self) // true
```

However, it doesn't work for dynamic types, such as metatypes passed into a function.

```swift
func conforms(_ itemType: Any.Type, to target: Any.Type) -> Bool {
    itemType is target // Error: Use of undeclared type 'target'
}
conforms(Bread.self, to: Edible.self)
conforms(Broom.self, to: Edible.self)
```

Is there any way to test for conformance to a dynamic metatype in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test for conformance using generics:

```
func conforms<T>(_ itemType: Any.Type, to target: T.Type) -> Bool {
    itemType is T.Type
}
```